# "Trust" vs. "Cartel"

Tags: meaning, differences, vocabulary, terminology

> The establishment of **trust** is quite difficult but for **cartel** it is comparatively easy.

What is the difference between **trust** and **cartel**?

Does the word "**oligopoly**" have a different meaning in comparison with both of the words above?

Comment: I think you meant to write "The establishment of **a** trust is quite difficult but for **a** cartel it is comparatively easy." Without "a", the "trust" makes sense but with a very different meaning, and the "cartel" doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: A "trust" is what you call a "cartel" you like.  (Though it used to be that folks didn't like trusts either.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Trust**: a group of companies that illegally work together to reduce competition and control prices. As Yitchak mentions the word gained its connotations of illegality after the US anti-trust laws targeted trusts and defined them as "a conspiracy in restraint of trade."

**Cartel**: a group of people or companies who agree to sell something at a particular price.

**Difference**: The goal of a trust is to reduce competition and eliminate competitors. But in cartel the goal is to sell at a particular price and not necessarily eliminating competition. OPEC is an example of cartel.

Answer (score 6):

A trust was a particular kind of oligopoly used in early 20th century America to prevent competition. Technically, it is a cartel run by a board of trustees not necessarily as a conspiracy to prevent competition. The word gained its connotations of illegality after the US anti-trust laws targeted trusts and defined them as "a conspiracy in restraint of trade."

As a completely irrelevant (and irreverent) aside, many libertarians find these laws slightly amusing since they define the federal government itself the same way. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Cartel and trust can both mean the same thing: a group of companies or organisations who (illegally) collude to fix prices/eliminate competition/etc. I hint at illegality, because in my country this behaviour would be illegal - but perhaps it isn't in other countries.

If there is a difference between the two, it might be that technically a trust would be run by a board of trustees ([See 10a](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trust)), whereas there is no specific organisational structure assumed with a cartel.

In my experience, cartel is most commonly used.

Oligopoly is different; it simply means that there are a small number of organisations dominating the market or industry - there is no inference that they are colluding or co-operating in any particular way.